# value in textbox cannot be refreshed by a global variable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a windows app.  On one of the forms(say form A), there is a button next to a textbox. when you click the button, there is a popup window with a textbox and buttons ok an cancel on it, user can enter some text on the popup window txtbox, and then click OK button to close this popup. I used a global variable to hold this user entered value and when the popup closed the value should be displayed on the textbox in form A. the problem is when I run it the textbox doesn't get to display the value.
I declared a sub in form A to set the textbox to be the global variable, and in the popup window btnOk click event call this sub before close, I can see my msgbox run and display right value, but the txtbox in form A is blank. I really don't know what I did wrong, please help, I really appreciate!!

here is my code:
in popup window

```
Private Sub btnOk_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
               ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
    ...
    gExpText = txtexp.text
    Call frmA.refreshtxt() ' not working
    'frmA.txtbx.Text = CStr(gExpText) 'not working
    'frmA.txtbx.Refresh()            'not working
    '
    Me.Close() 
end sub
```

--------------- in form A------------

```
Public Sub refreshtxt()

    txtbx.Text = CStr(gExpText)
    txtbx.Refresh()
    'txtbx.Update()

    MsgBox("hello")
    MsgBox(gExpText)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can declare a Property in the pop up window(say FormB), then on a button click event, store the value to property. and access it from FormA.

-In FormB

```
 Private _gExpText As String
   Public Property GExpText () As String
      Get
          Return _gExpText 
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As String)
          _gExpText = value
      End Set
 End Property

 Private Sub btnOk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
    GExpText = txtexp.text
    Me.Close()
 End Sub
```

-In FormA

```
 Public Sub refreshtxt()
    Dim formb As New FormB
    formb.ShowDialog()
    txtbx.Text = formb.GExpText 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But how do you call Sub refreshtxt()?

Comment: It's depends on how you wanted to trigger the pop up of Form B. As you said you got a button in Form A next to a textbox. You can call the refreshtxt() function from the button click in Form A